# Verificar se o e-mail já foi enviado

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte funcionalidade no meu código PHP.

```
    // Envia o e-mail
    $enviado = $mail->Send();

    // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();


    if( $enviado ){
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

Assim que realizado o Submit na página, dispara um e-mail utilizando à funcionalidade acima, porém
se eu der F5, outro e-mail é enviado.
Gostaria de saber se mesmo eu atualizando a pagina (F5) eu consigo enviar apenas um e-mail ?

Obrigado.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no pattern PRG, provavelmente irá te ajudar. http://wordsideasandthings.blogspot.ca/2013/04/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-php.html

Comment: você pode redirecionar a página em caso de sucesso e pode substituir aquele código por `return $mail->Send();`, depois, fora da função redireciona ou não.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if( $enviado ){
      echo "<script>alert('E-mail enviado com sucesso!')</script>";
      header("Location: index.php");

        } else {
        echo "<script>alert('E-mail não foi enviado')</script>";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente criar uma `$_SESSION` ao enviar o e-mail, fazendo que seja possível enviar outro e-mail apenas depois que o visitante reabrir o navegador ou você limpar as sessões.

Mais informações sobre SESSIONS: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php

Espero que tenha ajudado. :D